# Correct the below query to run in sqlplus mode

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

```
SELECT Sum(SumCount) AS TotalCount FROM(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS SumCount FROM IFSP01.COUNTER000
where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter001 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter002 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter003 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter004 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter005 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter006 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter007 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter008 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter009 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter010 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter011 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter012 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter013 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter014 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter015 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter016 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter017 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter018 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') union
select count(*) from counter019 where serverid=2 and  timestamp<to_timestamp('12-06-2017 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))dt;
```

When I pass this query in shell script and execute it via sqlplus mode I receive an error stating that the number of lines are high and so it is failing to execute, Can we change the query to have less number of lines?

Comment: Does it have to be 1 query?

Comment: What is the **exact** error message you get? **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: I do not think 'optimize' is the correct word, especially since this question is related to DB.

Comment: You only have 22 lines. I have just run a single SQL statement with 1733 lines. Works fine. Whatever you are using to pass in the SQL to SQLPLUS is your limitation. You need to fix that as 22 lines is not much for a query.

Comment: Are you perhaps passing the whole thing as a single line and getting `SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored`? What you're posted is a bit above that limit. We shouldn't have to guess, of course - why not show the actual error you get, and your shell script, in your question?

Comment: @Nitish - so you believe it is impossible to optimize database queries?

Comment: @APC: Not at all. When I read the question title, I thought it was related to performance. This question is nowhere related to performance. I'm sure many people would have thought the same. A Google search of 'optimize query sqlplus' is giving me this question as the 5th result, whereas all other results are about performance tuning.

Comment: yes @Whencesoever

Comment: thanks all it worked